# Apple push notification issue for status true

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I am sending apple push notification from java. I am getting true for pushedNotification.isSuccessful(). But push is not getting on ios device for that device token.

What can be the issue?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, were you ever able to resolve?

Comment: I found issue in p12 certificate. given device tokens are not registered to p12 I am using. Try replacing p12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolved.
I found issue in p12 certificate. given device tokens were not registered to p12 I am using.

Comment: Ah thanks, my issue was a bit different but resolved it nonetheless.